# What does oplus symbol ⊕ do for 2 images in Convolution Neural Networks

Tags: matrices, image-processing, neural-networks

So I'm reading this paper on optical flow prediction from two image frames, and I'm having a difficult time finding what this operator does. This paper, and some other ones uses it on the outputs of convolution neural networks.

http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2017/papers/Ranjan_Optical_Flow_Estimation_CVPR_2017_paper.pdf

I looked up math symbols and saw that it was an xor operator in logic, but that doesn't make any sense to me in this context.

I would also like to know what to call this symbol for future reference.

Comment: In the paper you linked I only see it used in figures. Those schematics resemble the data flow programming of languages like simulink, and just means sum in that context.

Comment: Oh, so it would be pure and simple matrix addition?

Comment: It depends on the type of object that the wire carry... in this case I think that it is more a tensor sum.

Answer (score 2):

The symbol is called "oplus" or "circled plus". In TeX it is written \oplus and looks like this: $$\oplus$$

Depending on context, it could denote

- exlusive or (XOR)
- dilation (morphology)
- direct sum

Here is the [disambiguation page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%8A%95).

---

I don't know anything about morphology.

However, given that your question is related to handling images mathematically, I'd guess that [**dilation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_(morphology)) is what your $\oplus$ denotes.

Comment: I second your guess.

Comment: So in my context of images it would be dilation (morphology)?

Comment: Yes. There's also a [Kronecker sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerSum.html), another use of oplus that isn't relevant here :)

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not convinced that dilation morphology is what is going on. In the paper, the input to the oplus are two images, and the output is a new image. Dilation morphology would expect a smaller matrix with a single image.

Comment: "Dilation morphology would expect a smaller matrix with a single image." Are you sure*? I admit I don't know enough about morphology, but that seems at odds with what I'm reading

Answer (score 0):

So I asked a colleague about the operation and he says the oplus symbol refers to concatenation of the last dimension in the area of computer vision.

So if image1 had shape (w,h,3) and image2 had shape (w,h,3)

image1 $\oplus$ image2 = image3 with shape (w,h,6)

I'd like to confirm whether or not this is true.